# display the months of a specific category

Tags: php, categories, list

I have a website made in wordpress, this website has a file called category-intranet.php that is responsible for showing me all the posts of the category "Intranet". what I need is that when the visitor reaches this point, on one side you see all the posts of the category "intranet" and on the other a kind of sidebar that shows the months ONLY of the category "Intranet". I tried with **get_month_link()**, but this shows all the months of all posts and this does not serve me. here I leave my code

```
            <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                the_archive_title( '<h1 class="headline color-black">', '</h1>' );
                echo '<br>';
                if ( category_description() ) {
                    echo category_description();
                }
                ?>
            </header>
            <div class="grid">
                <?php
                // Start the loop.
                echo '<div>';
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();
                    echo '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
                    echo '<div class="post-access">';
                    the_title( '<h3 class="standard medium color-black">', '</h3>' );
                    echo '<p class="standard color-black">' . get_the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) . '</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</a>';

                endwhile;

                // Previous/next page navigation.
                the_posts_pagination(
                    array(
                        'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                        'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                        'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
                    )
                );
                echo '</div>';
                endif;
                echo '<div>';
                if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        the_post();
                        echo ' <div class="month">
                                <a href="' . get_month_link( '', '' ) . '">
                                    <p class="standard color-black">' . get_the_time( 'F Y' ) . '</p>
                                </a>
                        </div>';

                    } // end while
                } // end if
                echo '</div>';
                ?>
```

Obviously and before asking here I have used the search engine of the forum and google and I have not found anything.
Thank you very much

PS:
I also have the archive-intranet.php so that the visitor can get here after clicking on the url

Comment: there's no dedicated function for this as categories don't have pretty URL date archives, so `get_month_link` won't lead to a page filtered by your intranet category, but all posts in all categories for that month. The closest you can get out of the box is `wp_get_archives` but that will list months for all categories, not just intranet. Of note, you would need to implement your month URLs similar to this: `example.com/2022/02/?cat=1234`, if you add the parameters to the category URL then the date archive rewrite rule matches first and you get redirected and lose your category filter

Comment: also, your current implementation only shows the months for the posts on the current page, and can't show follow up pages, so looping through the posts isn't a feasible solution